# yathesis class, add library number

Tags: yathesis

In the class yathesis, how can I add a library reference number (my university is asking me to add this item on the cover). The library number should appear above the title of the dissertation.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can try `\ordernumber[⟨number⟩]`.

Comment: It works ok. Thanks a lot!!